How can I apply @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports only for detecting type or interface
I have observed that @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports declare my class component as a type in the import declaration:
import type { Client } from "../shared/domains/client";

I expected to have:
import { Client } from "../shared/domains/client";

I think that when we declare:
import type AType from "./Abc"

we are sure that AType is a type or an interface from an exported declaration.
I feel weird to see:
"import type AClass from "./Abc"

and see that AClass is a class component instead of a type or an interface.
That is the reason I am asking if there is an option that we can add in order to use @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports and only apply the changes for a type or an interface exported component.

import type ... is used when you only need the type, not the value, of the import. So it doesn't matter whether that type is defined by: interface or type (and doesn't also have a value); or class or (non-const) enum (and does). But either way you can see the options available in the docs.

Thanks for the clarification @jonrsharpe

As said by @jonrsharpe
import type ... is used when you only need the type, not the value, of the import.
import: Importing Both Types and Values
The import statement is used to import both types and values (functions, classes, variables, objects, etc.) from a module. When you use a regular import, TypeScript will import the type information along with the actual runtime values.
import type: Importing Only Types
The import type statement, introduced in TypeScript, is used to import only the type information from a module. It indicates that you are interested in using the types of exported values but not the actual runtime values.
Additionally, we use import type to use the type for type-checking purposes without including the actual runtime values of the module in the emitted JavaScript code.
Reference:
https://medium.com/@quizzesforyou/import-vs-import-type-in-typescript-8e5177b62bea
